# Which is quicker cURL or fsockopen?

Tags: php, curl

I need to call two or three known URLs really quickly. I am writing a command line app where speed is imperative!

Does curl open a socket itself?

Are there any benchmarks?

Comment: Try them both and find out.  Besides, it's not enough to know that A is faster than B.  You need to know how much faster A is than B.

Comment: Why limit yourself... Does it need ssl and you just omitted?  B/c you could use wget, netcat, telnet, dropbear, or even straight bash.

Comment: It's most likely that the network is the bottleneck, not the code you use to make the connection.

Comment: https://github.com/rdlowrey/Artax

Comment: "php.net today that Curl was much faster then sockets, and much more reliable": http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10321912-Sockets-faster-than-cURL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say you're better off using cURL (yes, it opens its own sockets), because it knows HTTP better than cobbling a non-standard client together with fsockopen() and friends *probably* will.

And well - if you're absolutely *serious* about needing blazing fast HTTP-loadin' performance (define "really quickly"),  you'll have to use something other than PHP.

**EDIT:** Do the pages change often? If not, (mem)cache their contents locally and you shouldn't have too much problems.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I realize PHP is limited on speed and I will look into others but PHP and RoR and Jav#a (but Java is overkill) are the only languages I know how to call Restful APIs from. If you have any suggestions?

Comment: Again, define "really quickly" :) I'd say that for most practical purposes, your bottleneck will not be how fast you can push out an HTTP request, but how fast the other party will respond. You may also want to look into parallelizing the requests.

Comment: Both the client and the api will be on on the same network, dedicated boxes on the same subnet. As in HFT fast.

Comment: Alright, so that rules (should rule) networking out as a bottleneck. :) Well, cURL would have its own overhead, of course, but the only way you can find out which works better for you is to test whether there even is a measurable difference between cURL or some other method. Another method I could think of is a background job that does the queries as often as required (each second? more?) and stows the results in memcache or similar, which is tremendously fast.

Comment: I was thinking node because its non-blocking.